# Question marks in files but no errors in Markers

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex

I am using Eclipse to work on a large Flex project. Whenever I have an error in an actionscript file, it shows nothing in the "Flex Errors" section of Markers but when I open the file that has the error it shows a question mark next to the line where the error actually is.

Is there a way to show these questions marks in the markers section of Eclipse?

Let me know if you need more information!

Comment: They should show up in the errors and warnings panel.

Comment: Which is Markers right? They are not showing up regardless of what I do (rebuild, clean, refresh workspace, etc)

Comment: @AmyBlankenship, what's the "errors and warnings" panel?  I've never heard of that - sounds like it might solve this problem.  I'm seeing the same thing (markers in files, but can't figure out why since they don't show up anywhere else I can find.).

Answer (score -1):

If you roll your mouse over the question mark, it should show details.  Question marks were introduced in Flash Builder 4.5, I believe.  They are a kind of "highlight problems as you type."

Often these question marks will turn into yellow exclamations (AKA Warnings) or red Xs (AKA Errors) on saving the file.

However, if you using the include directive to include one ActionScript file inside another, it may show these question marks in the include file, even though there isn't actually a problem.

Comment: is there a way to show these question marks in the Markers panel?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.  As I say, they usually go away once you save the file.

Comment: What's happening is that real errors appear as question marks instead of appearing as errors so I am unable to find them but the build wont complete. Is there a way to increase the severity of these question marks to actual errors by default?

Comment: Real errors don't appear as question marks; they appear as red exclamation points.  If you have no errors what makes you sure your build isn't compiling. Perhaps you should post a screenshot or the code in question.

Comment: Well, my actual build (outside of eclipse) crashes as a result of a real error. When I open the file in question, it shows question marks that are only solved by actually solving the issue (referencing the right variable for example) so it was in fact a real error but it just shows that as question marks. ((Sorry, can't post code publicly :)))

Comment: Then there is nothing else I can do to help you.